# How to keep border formatting on Excel export

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

In my current SSRS report I have a tablix which has a border on every fifth line to visually separate the data.

To do this I added an expression to the bottom border style in the properties of my details section:

```
=SWITCH(RunningValue(Fields!Project.Value,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 5, "None", 
True, "Solid"
)
```

[image]

However when I export it to excel the border does not transfer over fully. Is there any way I can keep this formatting when I export it to Excel?

[image]

Comment: This is a bug, [filed on MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/778470/sql-server-2012-ssrs-export-to-excel-repeats-border-when-no-border-is-specified), whereby once a conditional expression has turned a border on, subsequent ones won't turn it off when they should - thus likely a duplicate of [Exporting Conditional Borders to Excel in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972277/exporting-conditional-borders-to-excel-in-ssrs). The oft-cited workaround involving making all the borders solid, and making the colour conditional instead, breaks web & PDF view :|

Answer (score 0):

[Another Posting on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972277/exporting-conditional-borders-to-excel-in-ssrs)

In the bottom answer to the link above helped me out.  I had the same issue as you are having.  When I made the Border solid & changed the border color through conditional formatting, that seems to work with the Excel export.  Now I don't have to re-conditional format in Excel when the order ID changes:

In border Color TOP:

```
=Iif(Fields!Orderid.Value = Previous(Fields!Orderid.Value) OR IsNothing(Previous(Fields!Orderid.Value)),"White","DarkBlue")
```

My BorderStyle in TOP is Solid. (I am using VS2012 and Office 365)