# SSRS 2008 Excel Export Issue

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using ssrs 2008. The report exports as expected in dev server and local machine. Whereas in Prod server the report is fine when exported to PDF but when exported to excel i am unable to view any borders.

UAT result is below
[image]

Comment: you need to adjust your page layout

Comment: can you provide screenshots of both situations (normal and without borders)?

Comment: What is the version of Excel on both machines? if they are the same are service packs installed on both machines?

Comment: Try to set the BorderColor to `Black` and the BorderStyle to `Solid`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer: Set the BorderStyle to be like this

```
BorderStyle = Dotted; ; ; ; Solid
```

source:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e11a0cf3-3494-437e-95e8-71a583c1c8eb/cell-border-formatting-gets-lost-when-using-excelexport?forum=sqlreportingservices

As well as, there is a different suggestion, you can find it below:

[Exporting Conditional Borders to Excel in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972277/exporting-conditional-borders-to-excel-in-ssrs)